# A question on the Lindelöf property and the Stone–Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactness

This question is from a paper I'm reading. I cannot understand this sentence in the poof of Theorem 1. It says:

> Suppose $X$ is not Lindelöf. Then there exists a compactum $C\subset \beta X \setminus X$ such that any $G_\delta$-set in $\beta X$ containing $C$ meets $X$. ($X$ is Tychonoff.)

Could anybody help me understand this sentence? Thanks ahead:)

See the paper by Raushan Z. Buzyakova, *[On absolutely submetrizable spaces](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc0603/buzyara.pdf)*, Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin. 47, 3 (2006) 483–490. Also available at [DML-CZ](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/119609).

Comment: What paper is this from?

Comment: What do you mean by "understanding this sentence"? Is there a problem with understanding the statement itself or only its proof?

Comment: @ArthurFischer See the link in the question:)

Comment: @t.b. Thanks for your link and your kindful reminding. The problem is the statement itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there should be a comma after Lindelöf.  Other than that, all I can do is paraphrase the statement, hoping that this helps.

Suppose $X$ is not Lindelöf.  In particular, $X$ is not compact.  Since $X$ is Tychonoff, $X$ has a Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$. 
As usual, we consider $X$ to be a subset of $\beta X$ and can now form the Stone-Cech remainder $\beta X\setminus X$.  The remainder is nonempty since $X$ is not compact.

Now the claim is the following:  There is a compact set $C\subseteq\beta X\setminus X$ with the following property:

For all $G_\delta$-sets $A\subseteq\beta X$ with $C\subseteq A$, $A\cap X\not=\emptyset$.

A $G_\delta$-set is an intersection of countably many open sets.
I hope this clarifies something.

You can get this compact set as follows:  Let $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of $X$ without a countable subcover.  This is possible since $X$ is not Lindelöf.  We can assume that the $U\in\mathcal U$ are actually open subsets of $\beta X$ so that no countable subcollection of $\mathcal U$ covers $X$.
$\mathcal U$ is not a cover of $\beta X$ since in this case, by compactness of $\beta X$, finitely many elements of $\mathcal U$ would already cover $\beta X$ and in particular $X$.

It follows that the compact set $C=\beta X\setminus\bigcup\mathcal U$ is nonempty.
Let $A$ be a $G_\delta$ subset of $\beta X$ with $C\subseteq A$.
Since $A$ is $G_\delta$, $\beta X\setminus A$ is the union of a countable family $\mathcal B$ of closed sets.  Each $B\in\mathcal B$ is compact and disjoint from $C$.  Since $C=\beta X\setminus\bigcup\mathcal U$, each $B\in\mathcal B$ is covered by $\mathcal U$ and hence by finitely many elements of $\mathcal U$.

It follows that $\bigcup\mathcal
B$ is covered by countably many elements of $\mathcal U$.
But $X$ is not covered by countably many elements of $U$.  It follows that there is $x\in X\setminus\bigcup\mathcal B=A\cap X$.
So $A$ meets $X$.  This finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks stefan for your answer. I will take some time to take it up.

Comment: Your answer is very clear for me and very helpful. One thing I don't understand what is why we can assume that the $U\in \mathcal{U}$ are actually open subsets of $\beta X$? Because $X$ is open in $\beta X$?

Comment: Sorry that this was not clear.  Start with an open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$.  Here $\mathcal U$ is a family of open subsets of $X$.  Now embed $X$ into $\beta X$.  Since $X$ is a subspace of $\beta X$, for every open subset set $U$ of $X$ there is an open subset $V$ of $\beta X$ such that $V\cap X=U$.  It follows that we can "blow up" each $U\in\mathcal U$ to an open subset of $\beta X$ whose intersection with $X$ is just $U$.   Now I have a family of open subsets of $\beta X$ whose union contains $X$.  I call this family also an open cover of $X$.

Comment: Now I see. It is abtained by "blow up". Thanks again.